# La función cin no me la ejecuta correctamente (C++)

Tags: c++, qt, funcion

Lo que sucede es que descargué Qt Creator y cuando uso la función cin no me guarda la variable y nunca termina de ejecutar, se queda en donde le pido el valor.
El código me funciona en otra plataforma como https://www.onlinegdb.com/ pero en Qt no.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int y;

  cout << "ingrese un num: ";
  cin>>y;

  cout << "El número es: " <<y;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Donde pone `#include` es `#include <iostream>` . Supongo que será una errata, no?

Comment: ¿Elegiste aplicación de consola cuando creaste un nuevo proyecto?¿Configuraste bien el archivo *.pro? Debes tener algo como `CONFIG+=console` y nada referente a `gui`